# Athena - count of case statement

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

Trying to execute the following in AWS Athena. This seems like standard SQL to me:

```
select
  count(case when gender='Male' then 1 end) as male_count
  count(case when gender='Female' then 1 end) as female_count,
  count(case when gender is null then 1 end) as other_count,
  count(*) as total_count
from onepercentsampleflattened_90days_parquet;
```

I get the following error:

```
 line 3:3: mismatched input 'count' expecting {<eof>, ',', 'from', 'where', 'group', 'order', 'having', 'limit', 'union', 'except', 'intersect'} (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception; request id: d7ccbaef-e5da-4fca-8ae8-60fb8b93ce6c)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You are missing a comma after the first `count()` expression.

Comment: better use "group by". More concise.

Answer (score 4):

you should add comma after the first count, also using count will give you same count for all records, you should use sum